# How to values such as age group in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Here I have datasets including age of customers of the business, I want to create an age group in a new column like "18-24", "25-34" and so on, what's the syntax I can use?

searching on google, I found this query

```
SELECT Year_Birth,
    CASE
        WHEN Year_Birth BETWEEN 1990 AND 1996 THEN "18-24"
        WHEN Year_Birth BETWEEN 1989 AND 1980 THEN "25-34"
        WHEN Year_Birth BETWEEN 1979 AND 1970 THEN "35-44"
        WHEN Year_Birth BETWEEN 1969 AND 1960 THEN "45-54"
        WHEN Year_Birth BETWEEN 1959 AND 1950 THEN "55-64"
        ELSE "65+" 
    END as Age_group,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM marketing_campaign;
```

but seems like this doesn't work

Comment: You don't want to be hard-coding years obviously, you need to calculate based on the current date.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! *Doesn't work* doesn't help us understand your problem. Please [edit] your question. And, by the way, persons born in 1990 are now 32 years old, whilst persons born in 2020 are two years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this field to a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT Year_Birth,
    CASE
        WHEN Year_Birth BETWEEN 1990 AND 1996 THEN "18-24"
        WHEN Year_Birth BETWEEN 1989 AND 1980 THEN "25-34"
        WHEN Year_Birth BETWEEN 1979 AND 1970 THEN "35-44"
        WHEN Year_Birth BETWEEN 1969 AND 1960 THEN "45-54"
        WHEN Year_Birth BETWEEN 1959 AND 1950 THEN "55-64"
        ELSE "65+" 
    END as Age_group,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM marketing_campaign
GROUP BY Age_group;
```

Note that must be an OLD article, that arithmetic is pretty far off now...... making this query work year on year is another problem but was not covered in your question.

Comment: I found that in order for this query to work, I need to put the values in between from small to big. Thanks, I have another question, so I have this temporary column of age-group, what statement can i use to add this into my table?